# Permission denied in Kannel server

Tags: modem, sms

Kannel Server is giving me this error on /var/log/kannel/smsmodem.log

I have a **Centos 7** server with **kannel-1.4.4**

```
2020-07-23 17:39:00 [4245] [6] ERROR: System error 13: Permission denied
2020-07-23 17:39:00 [4245] [6] ERROR: AT2[modemgsm]: Couldn't connect (retrying in 10 seconds).
```

Answer (score 1):

I already solve it

The serial port, where the modem is, has permissions for the *dialout* group.

```
# ls -la /dev/ttyS*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 jul 21 17:48 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 ene 21  2020 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 66 ene 21  2020 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 67 ene 21  2020 /dev/ttyS3
```

I only included user *kannel* in group *dialout*

```
# usermod -a -G dialout kannel

# cat /etc/group | grep dialout
dialout:x:18:kannel
```

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

SELinux is enabled preventing network access of the service to another. You need to allow service "A" to access service "B" local socket or port.

Consult details in [CentOS documentation](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)

Command Audit2Allow should help you figure out what's going on, more about on [RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow)

I'd recommend to learn the SELinux instead of disabling it.